# Abaqus UMAT [Fortran]: how to call a function from another function without getting "unresolved external symbol"

Tags: fortran, abaqus

I am currently working on implementing a material model in an Abaqus UMAT. The code is structured like this

```
MODULE FUNCTIONS
CONTAINS

FUNCTION GET_A(...) RESULT (A)
  IMPLICIT NONE
! ... some variable declarations
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: A

! ... some code

END FUNCTION

FUNCTION GET_B(...) RESULT (B)
  IMPLICIT NONE
! ... some variable declarations
  DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(n) :: B
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: DUMMY_VAR, GET_A

  DUMMY_VAR = GET_A(...)
! ... some code

END FUNCTION


END MODULE FUNCTIONS


SUBROUTINE UMAT(...)
! ... a lot of definitions
! ... a lot of code

END SUBROUTINE UMAT
```

I don't think it matters, but the imaginary function 'GET_B' is supposed to return an array. If a function does not depend on another function, I can call it from the UMAT without a problem. If I try to run the schematic UMAT from above I will get a compiler error similar to

*UMAT.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol get_a referenced in function functions_mp_get_b.R*

I read somewhere, that I am not supposed to declare the type of 'GET_A' within 'GET_B'. When I do that and change the code to

```
MODULE FUNCTIONS
CONTAINS

FUNCTION GET_A(...) RESULT (A)
  IMPLICIT NONE
! ... some variable declarations
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: A

! ... some code

END FUNCTION

FUNCTION GET_B(...) RESULT (B)
  IMPLICIT NONE
! ... some variable declarations
  DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(n) :: B
  DOUBLE PRECISION :: DUMMY_VAR

  DUMMY_VAR = GET_A(...)
! ... some code

END FUNCTION


END MODULE FUNCTIONS


SUBROUTINE UMAT(...)
! ... a lot of definitions
! ... a lot of code

END SUBROUTINE UMAT
```

the error changes to

*UMAT.f(some_line): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [GET_A]
DUMMY_VAR = GET_A(...)*

What can I do to call 'GET_A' from 'GET_B' (both functions are in the some module)? Do I need to put the return type of a function before the 'FUNCTION' statement? Since I am used to using the 'RESULT (...)' statement, I usually declare the type in the function body.
If it helps to post the full code here, I will do so. I just thought that putting a schematic code here will help to cause too much confusion.

Edit: I uploaded the full code to this [repository](https://github.com/Extraweich/Nonlinear_Kelvin_Voigt_UMAT) on git, where I also added the .log file for the precise error. I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: I don't know the exact cause of the error, but in `subroutine UMAT`, do you `use FUNCTIONS` or `use FUNCTIONS, only: GET_B`? Or do you just call `GET_B`? If you aren't `use`ing the module, it might be able to recognize `GET_B`, but unable to determine the interface of the internal call to `GET_A`.

Comment: I `use FUNCTIONS` in the `subroutine UMAT`, but the problem seems to be unrelated to the subroutine, but rather stands on its own in the `module FUNCTIONS`. I had the impression that `GET_B` should be aware of the presence of `GET_A`, since they both are in the same module within the same file.

Comment: I also added a link to the repository with full code and log file.

Comment: Your log contains a decent number of compiler errors, but the most concerning one is `UMAT_NL.f(221): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [FUNCTIONS] 
        USE FUNCTIONS `. This suggests you have an issue with the compilation and the program doesn't know where to find the `FUNCTIONS` module

Comment: I use a similar UMAT for a linear model, which has an identical structure, but does not call functions within other functions. This UMAT has no problems with finding the `FUNCTIONS` module. So I am not sure if this is the main issue.

Comment: Are `GET_A` and `GET_B` referring to `GET_G01G2` and `GET_DEPS` respectively? Because in `GET_DEPS`, you are calling `GET_G1G2` (notice no 0 in the name), which doesn't exist. This causes the module build to fail, which probably causes all the other failures in the log.

Comment: This could very much explain it. I will immediatly check this when I get home. Thank you for seeing this and sorry for my muddleheadness!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Very well seen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to wrap this up, the error wound being that `GET_B` wasn't calling `GET_A`, but rather `GET_A0`, a typo of `GET_A` which didn't exist and caused the compilation failure.

Some nice little debugging take aways that I have learned (and still have to remind myself to actually follow through with):

1. Try to reduce the bug down to as small an example as possible. This can help to avoid X/Y problems where you think the big is caused by X (function calling another function), but it's really due to Y (typo in function name).
2. Once you have narrowed it down as much as you can, use this as your test bed for determining the bug or as an example that someone else can run to reproduce the bug. This is for similar reasons to 1, where if you narrow in too much on a possible cause, you may make it impossible for someone else to reproduce the problem.
3. Programming bugs tend to be boring, to the point where they are easier to overlook. Far more (though by no means all) of the bugs I have created have been simple typos, transpositions of function arguments, missing or not run functions calls, etc rather than messed up algorithm design or some tricky quirk of the programming language. I'll many times jump to trying some elaborate testing to determine the cause of bug, when I would be better served just doing basic sanity checks.

Comment: Simplest in Fortran is always to have an interface in scope for called routines, and use the appropriate compiler flag to warn, or better error, when it can't find one - you declare all your variables, why not your procedures? For gfortran the flag is `-Wimplicit-interface` possibly coupled with `-Werror`

Comment: Fair point. To be honest I do not use Fortran for anything else but Abaqus and I must admit that my debugging routine could be better. I do not compile the subroutine manually, but I should look into having a small program to test my modules. What do you mean with I do not declare my procedures? I had the impression that declaring the result variable in a function would just do that.

Comment: I mean you should provide an Interface for your procedures which is in scope at the calling point - simply having them all in a module is the best way to satisfy this requirement. This is more than just declaring the return type, if you know C or C++ think function prototypes, only more powerful.